Accessing second project code within Gitlab docker executor
We have following project repository structure in out self-hosted GitLab instance
-Group

Project 1
Subgroup

Project 2



When the Project 1, is built, its package.json refers to code in project2 as a dependency.

We have a gitlab-runner with a docket executor which builds the Project 1's code. When the pipeline is run as we understood, the code of project1 will be checked out as gitlab-runner user (which we think have read access to the code base). However when the yarn install command is run, it seems to be executed within the docker container as its root user giving us an error.
could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.myserver.io': terminal prompts disabled


Is there a way we can use the same gitlab-runner user to download this dependency
The project can be build in one of many runners. Therefore we cannot create a named runner unless its the only way to do it.

Glad of someone can help
This works smoothly in out Jenkins agent. We are expecting the same behaviour in GitLab as well
UPDATE: Shell executor also return a 403 error.  So the above is not docker related.
Even after updating Project 1's CI/CD job token allowlist  to include Pronject 2, we get the following error
Authentication by CI/CD job token not allowed from Project 1 to Project 2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.myserver.io/app/mobile-applications/utility-modules/Project2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

We tried the following format in the package.json, still with no luck


Did you add in ci/cd the token access ? Go to settings> ci/cd > Token access

I added Project2 to Project1's CI/CD job token allowlist
